# spectral measure of non-empty and open set is non-zero proof

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

-rudin-2th.pdf">http://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis--rudin-2th.pdf

Part d) on page 322 and his proof appears on page 324. I didn't quite understand his proof so I had a go at proving it myself:

Let $z$ be in $w$. Then, ${\sigma}(T)$\ $w$ and $z$ are closed disjoint so by Urysohn's lemma there is a continuous function $f:{\sigma}(T)->[0,1]$ such that $f(z)=1$ and $f({\sigma}(T)\setminus w)=0$. Let $G$ be the Gelfand transform. By surjectivity there is a $S$ in the algebra $A$ such that $f=G(S)$. Then, $$S=\int_{{\sigma}(T)}^{}G(S)\,dE=\int_{w}^{}G(S)\,dE=\int_{{\sigma}(T)}^{}G(S){\chi}_{w}\,dE=E(w)S,$$ where the last part follows from the fact that the integral is multiplicative. So since $f$ is non-zero, $S$ is not zero and hence we must have $E(w)$ is the identity. The problem is that if this was correct, the proof would not merely say the measure is non-zero, it would say it is the identity. So where is the error and how to rectify it?

EDIT: @danielfischer For some reason I can't post comments. $E(w)$ is a member of B(H) so how can it have $S$, which is another member of $B(H)$ as an eigenvector?
EDIT: That make sense, thanks

Comment: Sorry, not yet waken up entirely. Not an eigenvector as such, its range just needs to be contained in the range of $E(w)$. (Fixed answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So since $f$ is non-zero, $S$ is not zero

That's correct, but

> and hence we must have $E(w)$ is the identity.

isn't. All that follows from $S = E(w)S$ and $S\neq 0$ is that $E(w)$ is the identity on the range of $S$, but $\mathcal{R}(S)$ need not be the full space (and isn't, generally). $E(w)$ is a projection, so $S = E(w)S$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{R}(S)\subset \mathcal{R}(E(w))$.